# varnish fails during extension upload in magento marketplace

Tags: error, extensions, varnish, magento2marketplace

I was using xampp and windows for using magento platform in local environment, once creating the extension it was posted in marketplace but this time i cant able to post and varnish fails the error i can see is, below i have mentioned. how to solve this. its been a month i was struggling

**"The expected HTTP response code for an un-existent Magento URL page is 404, got 500 It could be because the FPM service is not ready yet or this Magento installation is broken.",**

Help me to solve this,

THANKS